# Python match at least 3 words in a set

Tags: python

I have str with a phrase, for example:

```
phrase = "My cat has two eyes and like to catch rats"
```

And I have a set of `words` that I would like to matche at least 3 of theses words in the phrase.

```
words = set(["eyes", "like", "cat"])
```

Currently I have the following code

```
found = bool(set(phrase.lower().split()) & words)
```

But it matches if any of the words are in the phrase, and I want at least 3 words matching.

What I can do to achieve this? I don't want to use `regex`.

Comment: Get the length of `set.intersection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. `&` performs intersection on the `set` objects. But instead of doing `bool`, you need to get the `length` and check whether it is >=3. Hence use this:

```
>>> phrase = "My cat has two eyes and like to catch rats"
>>> words = set(["eyes", "like", "cat"])

>>> len(set(phrase.lower().split()) & words) >= 3
True
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the length of the intersection is at least 3.

```
found = len(set(phrase.lower().split()).intersection(words)) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
from typing import Set


def words_matcher(phrase: str, words: Set[str], threshold: int = 3) -> bool:
    phrase_as_set = set(phrase.lower().split())
    common_words = phrase_as_set.intersection(words)
    return len(common_words) >= threshold
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if all words in your set appear in phrase you might check if it is subset i.e.

```
phrase = "My cat has two eyes and like to catch rats"
words = set(["eyes", "like", "cat"])
print(words.issubset(phrase.lower().split()))  # True
```